# You better keep me clean, or you might contract a nasty facultative parasite

Tags: riddle, wordplay, treasure-hunt

This one is going to be tricky:

> There is a famous band with my name in it.
>
> You better keep me clean, or you might contract a nasty facultative parasite.
>
> I come in many shapes and sizes.
>
> I have been featured in the background of a pic on charlie_swags instagram.
>
> You can put me almost anywhere.
>
> People neglect to use me when they think they are too cool for me.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Are you annn...

> Air Conditioner

My reasoning:

> Band: AC/DC; Parasite from fungal spores; Shapes/location: window, car, central etc.; Picture: 4th image on this IG at time of posting.; No one thinks of AC when they are cool.

Comment: I think you got the right answer! (Plus your band is slightly more famous than the one I've put...) +1!

Answer (score 4):

Are you

> A pool?

There is a famous band with my name in it.

> There's an American band called Drowning Pool which might fit the bill here...

You better keep me clean, or you might contract a nasty facultative parasite.

> The **brain-eating amoeba**, *Naegleria fowleri*, is a facultative parasite which can be found in unchlorinated (ie. unclean) swimming pools.

I come in many shapes and sizes.

> There are many shapes and sizes for swimming pools

I have been featured in the background of a pic on charlie_swags instagram.

> I hope it has been...

You can put me almost anywhere.

> They can be in-ground, above-ground, in-house, in the basement, on a cruise ship, on roofs, on any floor of a hotel, etc.

People neglect to use me when they think they are too cool for me.

> Too cool for the pool ;)

Comment: wow, i'm surprised this is wrong, especially after seeing this: https://www.instagram.com/p/BlhOLGxHPfg/?hl=en&taken-by=charlie_swags

Comment: "Great answer, nothing wrong with it, keep guessing" is a phenomenon we really try to avoid here. @Crozier, maybe you could give some feedback on why the answer doesn't fit the riddle, or failing that, maybe add some more clues so that the intended answer becomes unique.

Comment: @kayzeroshort Yeah, my sister guessed the same thing! :P